# Uneven particle system fall on a mesh object

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I created a distorted torus object, and I used particle system (hair) to put particles on it... I have 2 problems: the particles were not spread evenly on the object (I also used weight paint and vertex group to paint red every side of the object but it didnt change much although the hair system looks more even but not the particles) how can I fix this?
My second problem is that I want my particle mesh object to stick to my main object from one particular side of itself not from everyside... My particles are sesame seeds and some of them stick to my main object from their narrow sides not from large sides .. How can I fix this?
[image: my mesh object]

Answer (score 0):

To the rotation problem: you can change in the rotation tab the phase, which rotates all particles in the same angle. You can then randomize the phase a bit to get a more realistic result.
To your distribution problem: I cant really give you a solution for that. I recently ran into similiar problems. What i can tell you is, you need a god topology for the particle system, so more or less even size of your faces (maybe use a remesh modifier). I personally fixed my problem with the weight paint and the distribution by starting over with a complete new emitter object...